# simple php if statement generates parse error

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got this code

```
        if ( !empty( $ImStoreCart->cart->items ) {
        $count = $ImStoreCart->cart->items;
        echo "Items in Basket: ". $count;
    } else { echo "Your shopping basket is empty."; }
```

but I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

I've checked the code but cannot see why its failing to see the if statement that needs the {

Any ideas?

Comment: Missing `)` at the end of your if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was ")" missed in first line

```
if ( !empty( $ImStoreCart->cart->items )) {
    $count = $ImStoreCart->cart->items;
    echo "Items in Basket: ". $count;
} else { echo "Your shopping basket is empty."; }
```

Comment: And OP will never know what you changed and why...

Comment: thank you! So simple but I missed it for ages!!